# listjs sorts incorrectly after multiple clicks on header column

Tags: javascript, sorting, listjs

JSfiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2mU8k/2/

```
var options = {
    valueNames: ['starttime'],
    sortClass: "list-sort",
    page: 50
};

var list = new List("js-list", options);
list.sort('starttime', {
    order: "desc"
});
```

The issue is: clicking multiple times on the Date header causes the list to get incorrectly sorted.

This is reproducible after a few clicks in my application which has a hundred items to be sorted.
In the JSFiddle example above, it may take a number of quick clicks to reproduce the issue.

I suspect this is a race condition due to the amount of time it takes for a sort to be completed.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

UPDATE:
After further testing in other browsers, the above Fiddle seems to work fine in Firefox and IE.  Strangely enough, it also appears to work fine when the non-minified code is used directly in the JSFiddle and viewed using Chrome.

Here's a version using the minified version of list.js, which sorts incorrectly as described above when viewed with Chrome (Version 33.0.1750.154): http://jsfiddle.net/2mU8k/4/

And here's a fiddle using the non-minified version of list.js embedded directly in the fiddle and it seems to work fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/2mU8k/7/

So strangely enough, this only happens with the minified version of list.js and Chrome.

Comment: What browser are you using? Tried to simulate the error tons of times, but unfortunately I couldn't.

Comment: I am using Chrome - Version 33.0.1750.154.  What browser are you using?  Interesting enough, I just tried Firefox and IE and both seem to work fine.

Comment: I was using Firefox. It seems to be a Chrome glitch. Odd!